# Quicksort Multiple Variable [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

Goodday!
I am trying to sort a data (Name - age) by its age.
I have use the **QUICKSORT** algorithm and works fast for sorting AGEs but how do I sort Age with their respective name?

I also googled the Comparable and Comparator but I don't understand how to implement it with quicksort.

here is my code for quicksort.

```
private int array[];
private int length;

public void sort(int[] inputArr) {
    if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.array = inputArr;
    length = inputArr.length;
    quickSort(0, length - 1);
}

private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
    int i = lowerIndex;
    int j = higherIndex;
    int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (array[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // call quickSort() method recursively
    if (lowerIndex < j)
        quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
    if (i < higherIndex)
        quickSort(i, higherIndex);
}

private void swap(int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static void main(String a[]){

    GUIAdvanceSort sorter = new GUIAdvanceSort();
    int[] input = {5,4,3,2,1};
    sorter.sort(input);
    for(int i:input){
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `<` and `>` operators work on ints in the array but not objects.  You need to invoke a Comparator on the two objects to get the same information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3935827/954442

Comment: yes sir, but how do I stick together the Comparator and Quicksort?

Comment: Basically: `Collections.sort(myList, new MySpecialNameAndAgeComparator());`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the links and comments, you first need to create a `NameAndAge` class to encapsulate the two properties. Then you have two options:

1. Make `NameAndAge` 'naturally' comparable, by implementing  `Comparable<NameAndAge>`
2. If you don't believe they're inherently comparable, create a dedicated `Comparator<NameAndAge>` and apply it to a list.

I think (1) is the right choice here.

The following example is far from complete (`equals()` and `hashCode()` should be overridden), but it demonstrates natural ordering of `NameAndAge`: name first (case-insensitive), then age (ascending), and it works when using Java's existing `Collections.sort()` method.

What you need to do for your own algorithm is:

1. Switch your algorithm from dealing with `int` => `NameAndAge`, or ideally `Comparable<T>`
2. Instead of using < and >, use `current.compareTo(pivot)` instead.

`Comparable` example:

```
public static void main(String a[]){

    List<NameAge> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add( new NameAge("Zack", 2) );
    entries.add( new NameAge("John", 37) );
    entries.add( new NameAge("John", 11) );
    entries.add( new NameAge("John", 5) );
    entries.add( new NameAge("Andrew", 9) );

    Collections.sort(entries);

    for (NameAge each : entries) {
        System.out.println(each.name + " (" + each.age + ")");
    }
}

public static class NameAge implements Comparable<NameAge> {
    String name;
    int age;

    public NameAge(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo( NameAge other) {
        int nc = name.compareToIgnoreCase( other.name );
        if (nc != 0) {
            return nc;
        }
        return (age < other.age) ? -1 : ((age > other.age) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
Andrew (9)
John (5)
John (11)
John (37)
Zack (2)
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. but where can I insert my quicksort algorithm?

Comment: I'll see if I can paste my complete example later , but for the time being you just need to replace the `Collections.sort(entries);` line with a call to `sort()` and your `int[]` with `List<NameAge>` (or whatever name you use - obviously the above is an example)